# Making an order and receive the reservation_id that comes with it SQL, PHP, html5 form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a couple of forms:

In the first form I enter:
Reservation date, customer information, and the table i am assigning them for that date.

I the second form I enter:
Data to take an order, I enter in the date and the table and I want to know which reservation ID is linked to that.

Now i cannot figure out how to do this since the reservation date, table_number and reservation id are not getting pulled out of the reservervation table using the following query:

```
SELECT o.OrderID
        , o.MenuItemID
        , o.ReceiptID 
        , r.Res_Datum
        , r.Tafel_Id
        , r.Reservering_Id 
     FROM Orders o
     JOIN reserveringen r
       ON o.Res_ID = r.Reservering_Id 
    GROUP 
       BY o.Res_Datum
        , o.Res_ID 
        , o.Tafel_Id
```

This query does work though:

```
$sql = "
SELECT O.Res_Datum
     , O.Res_ID
     , O.Tafel_Id
     , O.ReceiptID
     , SUM(MI.ItemPrice) TotalReceiptPrice
  FROM Orders O 
  JOIN MenuItem MI 
    ON O.MenuItemID = MI.MenuItemID
 GROUP 
    BY O.Res_Datum
     , O.Res_ID
     , O.Tafel_Id  
";
```

Problem with this is that i have to enter everything manually even the reservation_id and then i can culculate what the total order price is of that table for that date.

I want the reservation_id from the reservation that is bound to the reserved table that day so i know who made what order. So I dont have to type it in manually.

I have looked up everything from JOINS, Vieuws, and multiple select statements but i cannot figure it out. Also tried foreign keys but this makes things even more confusing.

What I am trying to accomplish: 1.To make and vieuw reservervations and assign a table ( this works ) 2.To take an order, and see the totalorderprice of the table -> with reservation_id ( and date) ( this works but only when i enter the reservation_id manually into sql. )

Below is what I already have created. You see that I am almost done. Just need this last query to work, and would be very happy to know what I am doing wrong.

My database:

```
MenuItem: 
    MenuItemID  int(11)         
    ItemName    varchar(255)        
    ItemPrice   double

orders:
 OrderID    int(11)         
 MenuItemID int(11)         
 ReceiptID  int(11)         
 Res_Datum  date            
 Tafel_Id   int(11)         
 Res_ID     int(11) 


receipt:
ReceiptID       int(11)         
ReceiptPrice    double

reserveringen:  
    Reservering_Id  int(11)         
    Tafel_Id        int(11)         
    VoorNaam        varchar(255)            
    AchterNaam      varchar(255)            
    TelefoonNummer  varchar(255)        
    Email           varchar(255)        
    Res_Datum       date
```

Below I am going to add two of my php files for creating an order
If you copy paste the code from the 2 forms and use the same name you should be able to recreate.

Bestelling.php:

```
<form action="/restaurant/maak_bestelling.php" method="POST">
  <h2>Enter Order</h2>

  Table Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="tafelnummer" value=""><br><br>
  Receipt Id:<br>
  <input type="text" name="receiptid"   value=""><br><br>
  Menu_Item:<br>
  <input type="text" name="menu_item"   value=""><br><br>
  Date: <br>
  <input type="date" name="date"        value=""><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<h2>Pending Orders:</h2>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "restaurant";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//MY Query i am trying to run
// $sql = "SELECT O.Res_Datum, R.Reservering_Id, O.Tafel_Id,O.ReceiptID, SUM(MI.ItemPrice) AS TotalReceiptPrice
// FROM Orders, Reserveringen AS O INNER JOIN MenuItem AS MI ON O.MenuItemID = MI.MenuItemID
// AS O LEFT JOIN Reservering_Id AS R on O.Reservering_Id = R.reservering_Id
// GROUP BY O.Res_Datum, O.Res_ID, O.Tafel_Id  ";

//The statement I get with an Empty reservation_ID
$sql = "SELECT O.Res_Datum, O.Res_ID, O.Tafel_Id,O.ReceiptID, SUM(MI.ItemPrice) AS TotalReceiptPrice
FROM Orders AS O INNER JOIN MenuItem AS MI ON O.MenuItemID = MI.MenuItemID
GROUP BY O.Res_Datum, O.Res_ID, O.Tafel_Id  ";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Res_datum: ". $row["Res_Datum"]. " ReservationID : " . $row["Res_ID"]. " - Table_Number: " . $row["Tafel_Id"]. " Total Order Price: " . $row["TotalReceiptPrice"]." ". "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>


</div>
```

maak_bestelling.php :

```
<?php


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!$con) {
echo 'Not connected with server';
}

if(!mysqli_select_db ($con,'restaurant')) {
echo 'Database Not selected';
}

$tablenumber = $_POST['tafelnummer'];
$receiptid = $_POST['receiptid'];
$menu_item = $_POST['menu_item'];
$date = $_POST['date'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO Orders (orders.Tafel_Id, orders.ReceiptID, orders.MenuItemID,  orders.Res_Datum )
VALUES ('$tablenumber', '$receiptid', '$menu_item', '$date')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
  echo 'insert did not work';
}else {
  echo 'Order created successfully';
}

header("refresh:1; url=bestelling.php");





?>
```

I have two more files for creating the reservation,
The form looks like this may you want to have an impression:

```
<form action="/restaurant/maak_reservering.php" method="POST">
  Voornaam:<br>
  <input type="text" name="voornaam" value=""><br><br>

  Achternaam:<br>
  <input type="text" name="achternaam" value=""><br><br>

  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="email" value=""><br><br>

  Telefoonnummer:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" value=""><br><br>

  Tafel:<br>
  <input type="text" name="tafel" value=""><br><br>

  Reserverings Datum:<br>
  <input type="date" name="datum" value="dd//mm//yy"><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




<div id="Tafels">
<h3>Gereserveerde Tafels</h3>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "restaurant";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// $sql = "SELECT reserveringen.Tafel_Id, reserveringen.Res_Datum
// FROM reserveringen
// INNER JOIN tafels ON reserveringen.Tafel_Id=tafels.Tafel_Id";
// $result = $conn->query($sql);

//andere query welke ik heb geprobeerd met reservering nummer
//tafels.tafel_Nummer,reserveringen.Res_Datum,reserveringen.Reservering_Id FROM tafels INNER JOIN reserveringen ON reserveringen.Res_Datum = reserveringen.Res_Datum AND reserveringen.Reservering_Id = reserveringen.Reservering_Id

//$sql = "SELECT tafels.tafel_Nummer,reserveringen.Res_Datum,reserveringen.Reservering_Id FROM tafels LEFT JOIN reserveringen ON reserveringen.Res_Datum = reserveringen.Res_Datum AND reserveringen.Reservering_Id = reserveringen.Reservering_Id";
$sql = "SELECT Reservering_Id, Tafel_Id, Res_Datum, VoorNaam, AchterNaam FROM reserveringen ORDER BY Res_Datum DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "reserveringID: ". $row["Reservering_Id"]. " tafelnummer: " . $row["Tafel_Id"]. " - Reservering_datum: " . $row["Res_Datum"]. " " . $row["VoorNaam"]." ".$row["AchterNaam"]. " ". "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Please read about [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: I just want the receipt id with the associated table for that date, nothing else.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd care to link orders to reservations. What matters (normally) is which table ordered what, not who made the reservation for the table that ordered nachos.

Answer (score 0):

Reservations and the assigned tables:

```
select 
reserveringen.Reservering_Id
, orders.Tafel_Id

from reserveringen

inner join orders on orders.Res_ID = reserveringen.Reservering_Id  
inner join MenuItem on MenuItem.MenuItemID = orders.MenuItemID
inner join receipt on receipt.ReceiptID = orders.ReceiptID
```

Order, Table, Reservation and sum of Menu Item Price:

```
select 
orders.OrderID
, reserveringen.Reservering_Id
, orders.Tafel_Id
, sum(MenuItem.ItemPrice) as sum

from reserveringen

inner join orders on orders.Res_ID = reserveringen.Reservering_Id  
inner join MenuItem on MenuItem.MenuItemID = orders.MenuItemID
inner join receipt on receipt.ReceiptID = orders.ReceiptID


where orders.OrderID = ? --insert the OrderID

group by
orders.OrderID
, reserveringen.Reservering_Id
, orders.Tafel_Id
```

Comment: This is perfect, except I forgot I dont use the table Tafels, How would I do this because when I change the query it all falls appart. I updated my question

Comment: select 
orders.OrderID
, reserveringen.Reservering_Id
, reserveringen.Tafel_Id
, sum(MenuItem.ItemPrice) as sum

from reserveringen

inner join orders on orders.Res_ID = reserveringen.Reservering_Id  
inner join MenuItem on MenuItem.MenuItemID = orders.MenuItemID
inner join receipt on receipt.ReceiptID = orders.ReceiptID
inner join reserveringen on reserveringen.Tafel_Id = orders.Tafel_Id



group by
orders.OrderID
, reserveringen.Reservering_Id
, tafels.Tafel_Id

Comment: replace tafels.Tafel_Id with orders.Tafel_Id (I edited the answer)

Comment: Still getting 0 results, it must be reserveringen.Tafel_Id that I am looking for And reserveringen.Reservering_Id